# Schema.org type for generic pages or posts on a CMS

Tags: schema.org

I'm trying to determine the best possible Schema.org type to declare for the content section in the template of a content management system, which will handle regular news posts for small, local hospitality businesses. The type should represent the content of that page, which is likely to be a wide range of things.

The description for [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) pretty strongly encourages its use to be limited to the articles of a publication. For purely semantic reasons, I'm not sure if [`Blog`](http://schema.org/Blog) is appropriate in this case -- businesses won't be creating typical "blog" content but are more likely to be writing about upcoming events, special deals, awards, etc. Would [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) be appropriate in this instance?

Although I'm a fan of the Schema.org concept, I frequently find myself unsure how broadly or narrowly I'm meant to infer the meaning of a type. In such cases, is it safe to use a high-level element, such as [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork), or does this blunt the usefulness of the markup?

Answer (score 1):

I think using [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) is appropriate.
"Newspapers and magazines" (from its description) are just examples, not the only possible publication mediums. For example, every [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) is *also* an `Article`.

You even might consider the more specific [`NewsArticle`](http://schema.org/NewsArticle) type in your case, as you *are* publishing news posts (for using this type, it doesn’t matter who publishes them, or what they are about).